# Parse from html and process massive amount of data to sqlite using php

Tags: php, android, performance, sqlite

I have an android app for local transportation times such as public bus, ferry and underground which will need to work both online and offline.

When app needs to be working offline, I need to keep updated its database. However, I do not have access any kind of webservice or database from the municipality. So that, I have prepared a PHP script which will parse html content from the municipality's web page and exract times for each number of public bus, each combination of underground(from where, to where) and each combination of ferry(similar to the underground.). However, my problem is starting from here.
Parsing all these datas approximately 100k records and process them to the sqlite database is working really really slow.

I'm new with processing huge amount of data and php. So I can take any suggestions.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't your server do this processing and cache the db centrally. Then all the android app has to do is download a compressed version of the database for local use when offline. When the app is online again it can sync with your server to retrieve the latest data. You could even send the data in batches. Then you can just have this php script crawl and scrape for your data every day.